# Swift protocol for string interpolation

Tags: swift, protocols, string-interpolation

What protocol do I have to implement to control the way an object is represented within a string interpolation in Swift?

I wan't to specify what get's printed in something like this:

```
struct A{

}

var a = A()
println("\(a)")
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to implement the `Printable` protocol:

> This protocol should be adopted by types that wish to customize their
>   textual representation.  This textual representation is used when
>   objects are written to an `OutputStreamType`.

```
protocol Printable {
    var description: String { get }
}
```

There's also the `DebugPrintable` protocol when it's only for debugging purposes:

> This protocol should be adopted by types that wish to customize
>   their textual representation used for debugging purposes.  This
>   textual representation is used when objects are written to an
>   `OutputStreamType`.

```
protocol DebugPrintable {
    var debugDescription: String { get }
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printable.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/Printable) (Thanks @MartinR)

***Note:** As @Antonio and @MartinR mentioned in the comments, this doesn't work in the playground (as of Xcode6 GM anyway); that's a known bug. It does work in compiled apps.*

From the Xcode6 GM Release Notes:

> In Playgrounds, println() ignores the Printable conformance of
>   user-defined types. (16562388)

As of Swift 2.0 `Printable` has now become `CustomStringConvertible`.  Everything stays the same as before, you still need to implement

```
 var description: String { get }
```

But now its called CustomStringConvertible.  And debug is CustomDebugStringConvertible

Comment: Are you sure this works? I thought the same, tried on a playground and it shows something like `__lldb_expr_551.Test`. Regardless of `Printable` implemented or not

Comment: Also documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printing.html.

Comment: Interesting. It works in a compiled app, but not in a playground.

Comment: That's why... I knew it was `Printable`, but after verifying it didn't work, I thought I was just wrong. Instead it's the playground. Thanks @MartinR

Comment: @Antonio After some digging I found it mentioned in the Xcode release notes that the Playground ignores `Printable` (known issue).  Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the documentation link, I knew it was out there somewhere but I hadn't found it yet. I added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 5 Apple introduced Custom String Interpolation.

Suppose you have person struct with two properties name and age.

```
struct Person {
  var name: String
  var age: Int
}
```

If you wanted to add a special string interpolation for that so that we can print persons in descriptive way, we can add an extension to String.StringInterpolation with a new appendInterpolation() method.

```
 extension String.StringInterpolation {
       mutating func appendInterpolation(_ person: Person) {
       appendInterpolation("My name is \(person.name) and I'm \(person.age) years old.")
    }
}
```

Now If we print the person details like:

```
 let person = Person(name: "Yogendra", age: 28)
 print("Person Details: \(person)")
```

Output will be:

```
Person Details: My name is Yogendra and I'm 28 years old.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to put an alternative solution here:

The protocol for string interpolation in Swift is [`StringInterpolationConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StringInterpolationConvertible_Protocol/index.html). That is, any class which implements the protocol, can be constructed from a string interpolation.

Back to the question, to control what is printed out for a String string interpolation of instances of class `A`, you would need to create a String extension and overload the [`init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: A)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StringInterpolationConvertible_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfctr/StringInterpolationConvertible/s:FPs30StringInterpolationConvertiblecurFT26stringInterpolationSegmentqd___x) function.

```
extension String {
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: A) {
        //do custom work here
        //for example: self.init(expr.description)
    }
}
```

In case you are looking for a way to remove the annoying "Optional(...)" when interpolating Optional variables, which I think is the main reason why people would want to control how an object gets printed out, just have a look at the pod [NoOptionalInterpolation here](https://github.com/T-Pham/NoOptionalInterpolation).

Additional information (edited):
Confirm that overriding `description` will only work for your own struct/class, but not for existing struct/class such as `Int` and `Optional`.