# Equivalent to *args in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum: Int = 0
    for number in numbers {
       sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
sumOf(1, 2, 3) //6
```

This is sample code taken from the `Swift` iBook. It finds the sum of any number of arguments.

A python equivalent of this code would be:

```
def sumOf(*args):
    sum = 0
    for number in args:
        sum += number
    return sum
sumOf(1, 2, 3) #6
```

In python, *args accepts all variable types, so if I want to do this for whatever reason, I can:

```
def sumOf(*args):
    sum = ""
    for number in args:
        sum += str(number)
    return sum
sumOf(1, "test", 3) #"1test3"
```

How do I do this in `Swift`? How do I create a function that has a variable number of parameters of ANY TYPE? I don't need to do this, but I'd like to know how.

Thanks.

Comment: One of the central design aspects of swift as a language is strict typing. If you want to do anything with your list of arguments inside the function then all the arguments should at least conform to a common protocol (`Any` would be a protocol that every object conforms to, but it does not help you in any way other than satisfying the compiler - you cannot *do* anything with the objects). You then use the common protocol as the type of the variadic argument list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
func concatOf(args: Any...) -> String {
    var concat = ""
    for arg in args {
       concat = "\(concat)\(arg)"
    }
    return concat
}
```

Comment: Interesting, you basically imply `Printable` in your code, which `Any` does not conform to... yet it compiles (but the string interpolation does not return anything particularly useful for types that do not conform to `Printable` or `DebugPrintable`).

Comment: @ThorstenKarrer: Interesting indeed. (Although, it's quite incidental, and accidental, here, I just wanted to show the `Any` polyadic signature. You're right that you shouldn't be able to do anything useful with them.)

Comment: @ThorstenKarrer: Could maybe be the issue 16562388 referenced [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25816505/240443), documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html)?

Comment: seems more like the debugger will _always_ generate a string representation of an object regardless of it conforming to `Printable` or not. `Printable` allows you to customize that representation. The latter, unfortunately, is still broken in Playgrounds, which is the issue you mentioned.